# Setting State Array and Appending Value on Update

Tags: reactjs

I'm still learning about state and lifecycle with ReactJS and have run into a scenario where I have a form that on submit should save the form value and then append the returned JSON object to the end of an array which would re-render the component storing the original array.

With my current setup, I have the components setup and form submit with returned JSON object, but the state contains an empty array rather than the object spread `{...comment}` and it doesn't look like the setState is updating component, but that could be due to the empty array mentioned before. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Comment:**

```
import React from 'react';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

//record Comment - Comment Form Handle POST
class CommentForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            comments: []
        };
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    postComment(comment, recordId, csrfToken) {
        var body = { comment: comment };
        var route = 'http://localhost:3000/record/' + recordId + '/comment';
        fetch(route, 
            { 
                method: 'POST', 
                body: JSON.stringify(body), 
                headers: { 
                    'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken,
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })  
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                let commentsArr = this.state.comments;
                this.setState({comments: commentsArr.concat(data)});
            }) 
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    onChange(e){
        this.setState({
            value: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.postComment(this.state.value, this.props.recordId, this.props.csrf);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="record-comment__form">
                <div className="row">
                        <form action={"/record/" + this.props.recordId + "/comment"} method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value={this.props.csrf}/>
                            <textarea name="comment" className="record-comment__form-text-area" onChange={e => this.setState({ value: e.target.value })} value={this.state.value}></textarea>
                            <button type="submit" className="record-comment__form-button" disabled={!this.state.value}>Comment</button>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

//record Comment - Comment
const Comment = props => {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
                <h5>{props.user_id}</h5>
                <h4>{props.comment}</h4>
                <h3>{props.synotate_user.fullNameSlug}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
} 

//record Comment - Container
export default class Comments extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="record-comment-container">
                <CommentForm recordId={this.props.recordId} csrf={this.props.csrf}/>
                { this.props.record_comments.map((comment, i) => 
                    <Comment {...comment} key={this.props.recordCommentId}/>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Record (Parent component)(Where Comment is being set):**

```
//GET /api/test and set to state
class RecordFeedContainer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = this.context.data || window.__INITIAL_STATE__ || {records: []};
    }

    fetchList() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/test')
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })  
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.setState({ records: data.record, user: data.user, csrf: data.csrfToken });
            }) 
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchList();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h2>Comments List</h2>
                <RecordFeed {...this.state} />
            </div>
        )
    }
};

//Loop through JSON and create Record and Comment Container Component
const RecordFeed = props => {
    return (
        <div>
        { 
            props.records.map((record, index) => {
                return (
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 record-card">
                            <RecordCard {...record} key={record.recordIdHash} user={props.user} />
                            <Comments {...record} key={index} recordId={record.recordIdHash} csrf={props.csrf}/> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            })
        }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Where are you rendering `<Comments>` and how are you setting `this.props.record_comments` on that component?

Comment: Separate file, I modularized this setup. Will update questions and include that code

Comment: You need to share the state of `<CommentForm>` so that you can access `this.state.comments` when rendering `<Comments>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when rendering `<Comments>`, the  `this.props.record_comments` is not the comments you've updated in the state of the `<CommentForm>` component.  Each component has it's own internal state.

You need to pass the state along to your `<Comments>` component.  You will need to move your state up to the top level or use a state management system like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) which will allow you to access a shared state which could contain your comments array.

From the top level component you could manage the state there, like so:

```
this.state = {
comments: [],
// other shared state
};
```

You can pass along an update comments function, named for example `updateCommentsFunc()` to `<CommentForm>` like so:

`<CommentForm updateComments={this.updateCommentsFunc} recordId={this.props.recordId} csrf={this.props.csrf}/>`

Which will allow you to pass the updated comments back up to the parent component via something like:

```
const updateCommentsFunc = (newComments) => {
    this.setState({comments: [...this.state.comments, newComments]});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation. So with this proposed solution, I would convert `RecordFeed` to a stateful component and add the constructor with the empty comments array in the state?

Comment: Exactly, that is one of the ways. Try looking into Redux too, it has good benefits if you have time to experiment.

Comment: Sorry to bring this back up, but I'm struggling to figure out where the `updateCommentsFunc` would exist. Since it references `this.state.comments` and that exists as an array in the parent component, would this mean I would set this in the file where my parent component exists rather than the child component file? Should this also be a function within the stateful component meaning I drop the `const` and set it within `RecordFeed`?

Comment: Your `updateCommentsFunc` would be in the same parent component that holds the comments array in `this.state.comments`.  Pass a reference to that function along to your `CommentForm` so that it can call the function via the prop like so: `this.props.updateComments(['comment 1, comment 2', 'etc'])`.  This function should only exist in one location, not duplicated within another component, only call it there.  I realize these are fake internet points but upvoting anything (including this) that you find helpful would be the least you could do.

Comment: Also, feel free to open a new question if you want additional help that goes beyond this scope.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your `postComment()` function doesn't appear to be properly bound to your enveloping `<CommentForm/>` component's `this`. As a result; calling `this.setState()` from within the function isn't really doing anything.

Try binding it within your constructor method.

```
constructor(props) {
  // ...
  this.postComment = this.postComment.bind(this)
}
```

Or by declaring it using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
postComment = (comment, recordId, csrfToken) => {
  // ...
}
```

See [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56) for more info on React binding patterns.